# Obtaining half the width of an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate half of the width of an object using Javascript.

```
    var img = document.getElementById('picture1'); 
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var halfwidth = width/2;
```

I then need to plug that variable into a jquery css modifier for margin-left. This will be used to position the image in the exact center of the page.

```
    $('#div').css('margin-left','-400px');
```

but instead of -400px, I need to have the          variable in there somehow. Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
$('#div').css('margin-left','-' + ($('#picture1').width()/2) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple

```
$('#div').css('margin-left','-'+(parseInt($('#picture1').width())/2)+'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can position the image in the center of the page http://jsfiddle.net/JkZdH/

```
var img = $('#myImg'),
    docWidth = $(document.body).width(),
    imgWidth = img.outerWidth(true),
    marginLeft = (docWidth - imgWidth) / 2;
img.css('margin-left', marginLeft);
```

For html:

```
<img src="sample_image.png" alt="dog" id="myImg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#div').css({marginLeft : $('#picture1').width()/2});
```